# Why is this nested request not running in Node.js with Spotify API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, spotify

I am using the authorization code flow to have a user log in and allow me to access and create playlists on their account. I have followed along with the docs and I am now trying to read the users playlists but my nested request is not running. Here is my code:

```js
request.get(options, function(error, response, body) {
            console.log(body);
            if(response){
              request.get({url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/'+body.id+'/playlists',
                          headers:{ 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token },
                          function(error, res){
                            //var playlists = JSON.parse(response.body);
                            console.log("this code runs");
                          }
            })
            }
            
          });
```

As of now I retrieve the the users id, which does log to the console, and then pass the user's id to the next endpoint but the second request is not running. [I am using this endpoint](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/playlists/get-list-users-playlists/).

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is not working is because I passed the function as a property in the options object instead of the second argument. Here is the fixed code:

```js
request.get({
  url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/' + body.id + '/playlists',
  headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token }
},
  function (error, response, body) {
    //var playlists = JSON.parse(response.body);
    console.log("this code runs");
  }
)
```